# FIWARE Orion: no patterned entityId

Tags: fiware-orion

I get this error repeated every seconds on my instance of Orion:

```
time=Tuesday 26 Apr 13:21:47 2022.045Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=mongoSubCache.cpp[222]:mongoSubCacheItemInsert | msg=ERROR (no patterned entityId) - cleaning up
```

I suppose something is wrong with the ID of one of my entities in Mongo.
But how to find which?
I use v2.2.0 on Amazon ECS.

Comment: Orion 2.2.0 is very old (Februrary 2019). I'd suggest to upgrade to the newest one (3.6.0 at the moment of writting this) and re-evaluate if the problem stills appending.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a subscription with zero elements in the subject::entities array. You might want to locate it and remove it.